# UIVIew that will grow as I scroll down?

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, screen

so I want to make an app that will display 20 pictures on a longer than the screens length view. then after the user scrolls down all the way to the bottom and reaches the end, if he tries to scroll down more the view will get longer, and load another 20 pictures. Does anyone have any ideas of how to do something like that ? and advices or tips or a small tutorial would be greatly appreciates.

Thank you very much.

Comment: what have you tried to solve this issue? search for UITableView, lazy loading on stackoverflow or google.

Comment: I dont thing a UITableview would work in my case. But I have figured out how to display the pictures. The only thing that worries me is how to keep expanding the view..

Comment: why wouldn't it work? I mean, if you give a specific reason for it not working, you may get answers for workarounds.

Comment: Well the design I am doing for the pictures is not symmetrical and some of the pictures will be displayed in circular shapes, some others in square shapes, some will be 2 millimeters away from each others some will be 10, I dont think I can arrange this kind of design with a tableView. BUT if I am mistalen PLEASE TEACH ME HOW TO DO IT !!! haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the UITableView is perfect for this. You can have two sections in your table. First will contain cells with the pictures. The second will contain a cell representing a button for loading more images. If user taps this cell you simply load more pictures and increase the number of cells in UITableViewDataSource method.